# Is there a way to resize pictures based on the sibling element which contains text?

Tags: css

I have div container which holds two elements,
one contain text and the other one contains a picture
i want the height of my picture to resize based on its sibling container which holds text

for instance , if my text container's height is 500px, the height of my picture's container resize to 500px without losing its aspect ratio

Comment: have a look at css-grid

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_equal_height.asp

Comment: Didnt solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the type of implementation I have added here.
Make the image `height: 100%;`  and `object-fit: cover;` to fix the aspect ratio.

```css
body {
  max-width: 780px;
  margin: auto;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap ;
}

.child {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
.child img {
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/12004363/pexels-photo-12004363.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas ipsam eveniet cupiditate recusandae, ratione tenetur suscipit, quia est vel quasi, a ex maxime! Reiciendis quae delectus cum praesentium. Aliquid, necessitatibus?
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas ipsam eveniet cupiditate recusandae, ratione tenetur suscipit, quia est vel quasi, a ex maxime! Reiciendis quae delectus cum praesentium. Aliquid, necessitatibus?
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas ipsam eveniet cupiditate recusandae, ratione tenetur suscipit, quia est vel quasi, a ex maxime! Reiciendis quae delectus cum praesentium. Aliquid, necessitatibus?
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas ipsam eveniet cupiditate recusandae, ratione tenetur suscipit, quia est vel quasi, a ex maxime! Reiciendis quae delectus cum praesentium. Aliquid, necessitatibus?
    </p>
        <p>
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas ipsam eveniet cupiditate recusandae, ratione tenetur suscipit, quia est vel quasi, a ex maxime! Reiciendis quae delectus cum praesentium. Aliquid, necessitatibus?
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```